# Link to pdf within app

Tags: iphone, pdf, ios, uiwebview, plist

I've got an iOS app that at one point opens a link to a website in a webview. These links are kept in a plist file (so it is easy to maintain them as the app evolves). What I want to do next is to also link to PDF's (or any picture of text file format, of even a html format, this is flexible) that are kept within the app. And I would like to do this as much as possible from within the existing app structure. So, is it possible to create a link that can be put in the plist as a web-link, but instead opens a file on the device itself (possibly in the webview)? And how would I go about that? Any ideas?

Thanx in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create the links at runtime. I would suggest having a certain prefix to a local url, such as mylocalfile:filename. Then, in the code that loads the plist, check for the prefix and create the link when necessary. You could also just create these links once and store them in a separate file, then load that instead of the original.

```
NSArray *links = nil; //I assumed your plist is an array. Change to dictionary if required
NSString *pathToStoredFile; //Get the path for the file you create with the updated links
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToStoredFile]) {
    links = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToStoredFile];
} else {
    NSArray *tmp = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ListOfLinks" ofType:@"plist"]];
    if(!tmp) {
        //handle error
    }
    NSMutableArray *tmpLinks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[tmp count]];
    for(NSString *link in tmp) {
        if([link hasPrefix:@"mylocalfile:"]) {
            link = [link substringFromIndex:12]; //12 is the length of mylocalfile:
            NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] urlForResource:[link stringByDeletingPathExtension] withExtension:[link pathExtension]];
            [tmpLinks addObject:[url absoluteString]];
        } else [tmpLinks addObject:link];
    }
    links = [tmpLinks copy];
    [tmpLinks release];
    [links writeToFile:pathToStoredFile atomically:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would go with a UIWebView. iOS should be able automatically handle certain URL handlers and your app can [register to handle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1) the rest, as necessary.

iOS knows how to handle certain file types already. For example, if Safari (or a UIWebView) encounters `http://somesite.com/afile.pdf`, it know which apps can handle the file type. Another example is a phone number: `skype://8005555555`. iOS knows to open Skype and pass the number to it. iOS also knows that iBooks can handle PDf files.

Register your app for the appropriate file handlers and types. Then, users can tap and hold on the link to see a menu of available apps to handle the link. If it's a link that's only used by one app, the user doesn't even need to hold, a tap will suffice.

As far as making a link pointing to a local file, you can, and you would use the C function `NSDocumentsDirectory()` and append that to a url handler. (Example: `http://NSDocumentsDirectory()/filename.pdf`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't really get it. Can I make a link that is handled by UIWebView to load a PDF that is local? How would I do that? Do you have a startpoint or source of information for me?